# CXF java2ws: how to include external xsd files?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, jaxb2

I generate WSDL files for several web services (from the server service definitions) where I have already XML schemas (*.XSD) for the beans used as parameters. How do I tell java2ws to reference these (include the external XSD) and not generate its own into the WSDL?

I have tried the -createxsdimports, but that does generate its own XSD files.

Is there a Java Annotation that I can use to let CXF know where the XSD for each file/package is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`@XmlSchema`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) annotation.  It includes a `location` parameter that is used to tell JAXB that a real schema exists:

```
@XmlSchema(location="http://www.example.com/xsds/foo.xsd")
package com.example.foo;
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise, how do I define an xsd file in a local project directory. I tried file:/// but CXF (2.4.1) still gives me *no* schemaLocation="" on the <xsd:import ...>

Answer (score 2):

I have a CXF Webservice that imports external schema files. When I built it; I spent quite a bit of time trying to sort out the exact scenario you're trying to achieve. Unfortunately, it appears that CXF does not respect the @XmlSchema(location="") annotation when generating WSDL from java. Daniel Kulp, the main CXF dev told me at the time this was a known issue but not enough people are complaining about it so it's not high on their list of priorities to fix.

So I ended up writing the WSDL by hand and then generating the SEI from the WSDL file. Of course, if you hand-write the WSDL you can do whatever you want.

Do bear in mind that one side-effect of this is that the external schema file needs to be accessible by an HTTP GET - both while generating the SEI AND when the webservice app starts up  - CXF will retrieve the schema file on startup. Same goes for when you generate the client, of course. This does create a bit of a messy architectural dependency; but there appears to be no way to tell CXF "myschema.xsd" is available at http://myurl.com/myschema.xsd but ALSO in /src/main/schema/myschema.xsd.